# reconfiguration a numpy array RGB

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following data (RGB):

```
data = [np.array([[255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [173, 175, 181],
       [173, 175, 181],
       [173, 175, 181],
       [173, 175, 181],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255]])]
```

This is how it looks when I plot it:

```
plt.imshow(data)
```

[image]

However, I would like to plot the individual RGB components, but it's not working.

This is what I tried:

```
def rgb_component(data):
    rows, columns, colors = np.shape(data)
    arr_r = np.full(shape=[rows, columns, colors], fill_value = [255,255,255])
    arr_g = np.full(shape=[rows, columns, colors], fill_value = [255,255,255])
    arr_b = np.full(shape=[rows, columns, colors], fill_value = [255,255,255])
    for row in range(rows):
        for column in range(columns):
            for color in range(colors):
                # R
                if color == 0:
                    arr_r[row][column][color] = data[row][column][color]
                # G
                if color == 1:
                    arr_g[row][column][color] = data[row][column][color]
                # B
                if color == 2:
                    arr_b[row][column][color] = data[row][column][color]
                
    return arr_r,arr_g,arr_b
                
    

arr_r,arr_g,arr_b = rgb_component(data)
```

but it gives me this output for red for example, which is obviously false:

```
plt.imshow(arr_r)
```

[image]

Comment: What were you hoping for please?

Comment: Why is data a list?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The data is a list of RGB components that I would like to plot on the screen. Now, instead of plotting the perceived color, I would like to plot the individual RGB components.

Comment: @talonmies Why is this weird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[255,255,255]` corresponds to white. You initialized each of the colour channels with this and then modified the arrays of each channel with the data from the composite, so, in the red channel, only that center block has less red and therefore it appears blue.

If you initialized instead with `[0,0,0]`, you'll get this:
[image]

which I guess is not what you expected, but is truly the red component of your original image.